# How to change the font of chart axes?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, axes

How do I loop through the axes of a chart? the number of axes that the chart may have is variable, could be 1 or more...hence the loop. I have the following code:

```
Dim a As Axis
'
For Each a In ActiveChart.Axes
    a.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
Next
```

The above code gives the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/format-axis-font-in-vba/2fe979b0-1daa-415d-a550-c9e2c9d29fab?auth=1) on answers.microsoft.com, it seems to be a bug that was never fixed. As a workaround, you may use the following:

```
Dim a As Axis
For Each a In ActiveChart.Axes
    a.TickLabels.Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
Next
```